# java generics with more than 2 parameters

Tags: java, generics

i'm having a class Test where K, V, T - key, value, timestamp
i' m having an interface put( K key, V value, T timestamp)

my initialization of hashmap is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test1<K,V,T> {

    private final HashMap<K, TreeMap<T, V>> map = new HashMap<K, TreeMap<T, V>>(); 
    private void put(K key, V value, T timeStamp) {

     }

    public void put(K key, V value){
         // Here it gives compiler error
        put(key, value, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}


/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Test1<Integer, Integer, Long> classInstance = new Test1<>();
        classInstance.put(10, 10);
    }
}
```

But put here gives compiler error stating:

put(K, V, T) is not applicable for arguments (Integer, Integer, Long).

Can someone please help

Comment: Where is your `put` method defined?

Comment: I have edited the class definition.@OliverCharlesworth

Comment: The code is working fine for me

Comment: Cannot repro: https://ideone.com/Ora2qr

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I haveedited post to give you exact error.

Comment: Your problem is that the Test class doesn't know `T` is going to be `Long` at compile time.  So at compile time, it's looking for the third argument to be type `T`.

Comment: @aelfric5578 anyway i could do this in a different way?

Comment: Is `T` always going to be a`Long`  timestamp?  If so, then you don't need the third generic parameter.  Just have the class signature have `K` and `V` and initialize the `TreeMap` with `Long` and `V`

Comment: @aelfric5578 No I could have my T as Integer or any other TimeUnit type

Comment: Then initialize the TreeMap with `TimeUnit`, but you can't use a method like `currentTimeMillis`, which will always return a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I suggest is to declare your class abstract so you can leave to subclasses to define how their timestamps are obtained:

```
public abstract class Test1<K,V,T> {

    private final HashMap<K, TreeMap<T, V>> map = new HashMap<>();

    private void put(K key, V value, T timeStamp) {
        // ...
    }

    public void put(K key, V value){
        // Here it no longer gives compiler error
        put(key, value, getCurrentTimestamp());
    }

    protected abstract T getCurrentTimestamp();
}
```

This allows any reference type for `T` including `Long`, `Integer` or what you can imagine. Anyone wanting to use the class will then have to decide a type for `T` *and a way to generate an appropriate object* of type `T`. Here’s an example where I use `Instant` objects:

```
class Test1UsingInstant extends Test1<Integer, Integer, Instant> {

    @Override
    // declared return type needs to the same as supplied
    // as third type in Test1<Integer, Integer, Instant> above
    protected Instant getCurrentTimestamp() {

        // returned value needs to be of the declared return type
        // (auto-boxing will work, though)
        return Instant.now();
    }

}
```

This concrete subclass can then be used for example like this:

```
        Test1UsingInstant instance = new Test1UsingInstant();
        instance.put(10, 10);
```

The call to the two-argument `put` goes into the `Test1` class, where `getCurrentTimestamp` is called to obtain an `Instant`, which is in turn supplied as the third argument to the three-argument `put`.

Another example:

```
public class Test1UsingLong extends Test1<Integer, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long getCurrentTimestamp() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

Use in the same way as the first example:

```
        Test1UsingLong instance = new Test1UsingLong();
        instance.put(10, 10);
```

I have compiled and run all of my code.

`getCurrentTimestamp` may also be called a *factory method* for time stamps. In other words I am using the [*Factory Method* design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: This too doesn't work. Tried doing same. compile error: return type is incompatible with that of abstract class implementation of getCurrentTimestamp().

Comment: The code compiles and runs nicely on my computer. I have added a couple of comments in the code about requirements on the types used. Please have a look, @Vishal.